# Using a pandas method on multilevel index without the level argument

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking through Pandas documentation on multilevel indexing, and I'm getting stuck on one problem:

If I have a multi level index, and want to apply operations on a particular level of the index, I'm not sure how I would do this if the method doesn't have the `level` argument.

Here's an example:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/7/2020').tolist()], names=['Item', 'Date'])
series = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(21), index=index, columns=['Value'])
```

Let's say I want to standardize my values so they have mean 0 and std. dev 1 at the `Item` level, I can do this fairly easily in the following way:

```
series -= series.mean(level=0)
series /= series.std(level=0)
```

This is fairly trivial since both of these operations have the `level` argument.  Now the rows assigned to `A`, `B` and `C` all have 0 mean and std. dev 1.  However, lots of important operations **don't** have the ability to do this, and I'm not sure if there's a straight forward way, or if it would require a more elaborate grouping/merge operation.

For example, if I wanted to use a method like `pct_change` or `diff()` or something else that can't natively work on a multilevel index, what should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a groupby operation on the level of interest for methods that don't have the level built in:

```
series.groupby(level=0)['Value'].diff()
```

For your df would return:

```
>>> series.groupby(level=0)['Value'].diff()
Item  Date
A     2020-01-01         NaN
      2020-01-02    0.607607
      2020-01-03   -1.468150
      2020-01-04   -0.342008
      2020-01-05    1.292499
      2020-01-06   -1.043734
      2020-01-07   -1.390667
B     2020-01-01         NaN
      2020-01-02   -1.102930
      2020-01-03   -0.152588
      2020-01-04   -0.079328
      2020-01-05    0.976470
      2020-01-06   -1.706948
      2020-01-07    0.758684
C     2020-01-01         NaN
      2020-01-02    0.543588
      2020-01-03   -1.056940
      2020-01-04    0.575442
      2020-01-05   -0.894942
      2020-01-06    0.403182
      2020-01-07   -1.281761
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to apply your operation to the groupby object.

In the example that you give

```
series.mean(level=0)
```

is equivalent to

```
series.groupby("Item").mean()
```

or, more generally,

```
series.groupby("Item").apply(np.mean)
```

Note that this last variant may have an important performance impact.

I don't know if this applies to the situation that you had in mind.